# Count products and reviews of a brand using eloquent relationhips

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have three models:

```
class Brand extends \Eloquent {
protected $fillable = [];

public function product()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Product');
}
}



class Product extends \Eloquent {

protected $fillable = [];

public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Review');
}   

public function brand()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Brand');
}

}

class Review extends \Eloquent {
protected $fillable = [];

public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Product');
}   

}
```

I'm trying to display brand names along with product and review counts in a view:

```
{{ $brand->product->count() }}
```

it works for this, but doesn't display reviews count:

```
{{ $brand->product->reviews->count() }}
```

neither for:

```
{{ $brand->product->reviews->count() }}
```

Errors I'm getting are:

```
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$review

ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$reviews
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't call a relation on the collection of a model but only on the model itself. This means you have to loop over the products and count the reviews of each one of them.

Basically like that

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($brand->product as $product){
    $counter += $product->reviews()->count();
}
echo $counter.' reviews!';
```

Now this is very bad on database performance. First it queries the products and for each product it makes another request to the db. We can use [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading) to avoid this.

```
$counter = 0;
$products = $brand->product()->with('reviews')->get();
foreach($products as $product){
    $counter += $product->reviews()->count();
}
echo $counter.' reviews!';
```

With eager loading it loads all the data with one query and its already in memory when we do `$product->reviews()`

To finish things off here we can now put this in a function in the brand model

```
public function getProductReviewCount(){
    $counter = 0;
    $products = $this->product()->with('reviews')->get();
    foreach($products as $product){
        $counter += $product->reviews()->count();
    }
    return $counter;
}

{{ $brand->getProductReviewCount() }}
```

Sidenote: I would also suggest you change the name of the relationship `product` into `products`. It makes more sense and is usually convention to use the plural.

Answer (score 0):

I am using
        {{ count($brand->product) }}
        {{ count($brand->product->reviews) }}